# Conservation of momentum in statistical physics in presence of a potential

Tags: statistical-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, potential

Imagine a number of particles, all confined in a parabolic potential. The particles initially have a random velocity and are let free to bounce off each other (say, it's rigid spheres). Does statistical physics say anything in the case that the total initial momentum is different than zero? In particular, does it predict any of these scenarios:

1. the system decreases its total momentum, eventually reaching zero (e.g. no momentum conservation)
2. the system behaves in an analogue way to an harmonic oscillator (e.g. "average" momentum conservation)

Comment: To clarify, do you mean that the particles are confined in an external parabolic potential or that they interact with each other through a parabolic potential?

Comment: Please elaborate on the question; are the particles enclosed in a rigid box?

Comment: @BySymmetry clarified: it's rigid spheres in a confining parabolic potential, but I would not expect these details to matter, I just care about an overall confining potential being there.

Comment: @Harsha, I didn't mention one so no there is no closed box. Just the confining potential.

Comment: If the particles do not all have identical masses, I believe the center of mass will jiggle around: the average force will be determined by the average position, not the center of mass.

Comment: The system is under the action of a conservative external force, so if the total momentum is initially nonzero it will stay nonzero, i.e. the position of the center of mass of your system will change in time, probably in a periodic fashion, but I'm not sure about this last point. If the particles were point particles, the motion would be periodic.  But the hard sphere potential (collisions between particles) could result in chaotic behavior...I'm not really sure.

Comment: Noether's theorem states that momentum is the conserved quantity associated with translational invariance. In a parabolic potential, there is no such invariance, and also no reason why momentum should be conserved. Only the total energy is conserved and is statistically equally distributed among the particles at thermodynamical equilibrium.